# How to skip installing data files if not running as root?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have to deploy a Python project together with a script that is used via a command line interface. To help users, I also include a Bash completion file that is placed into `/etc/bash_completion.d`. Unfortunately, installing the source distribution with `pip install project.tar.gz` fails when installing as a normal user, because

```
error: could not delete '/etc/bash_completion.d/completion': Permission denied
```

Installing the project with `pip install -e .` works because the writing issue is ignored.

Now, is there a way to tell distribute that it should not attempt to write the data file when it's not executed as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [non-root option](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html?highlight=root#non-root-installation) in `distribute` which may be intelligent enough to spot that it can't write to `/etc` if you're not a super user (but I doubt it).

You don't say how your telling `distribute` to write to `/etc` but you might be able to put this in a `try:` and  `except:` clause (of course if this is automated in `setup.py` you may have to take that part out and do it manually).

If you're not sure if you can write to `/etc` before running the script (in the user case), you could just do

```
 try:
      with open('/etc/bash_completion.d/completion', 'w') eo:
          eo.write('test')
      data_files = ['completion', '/etc/bash_completion.d/completion']
 except error:
      print 'User does not have write access to /etc completion will not work'
      data_files = []

 setup(
      ...
      data_files=data_files,
      etc...
 )
```

Comment: I use the `data_files` keyword argument of `setup()` to specify that the completion script should be installed into `/etc`. Looks like it's really the only option to check inside `setup.py` if it is executed as root or not.

Comment: I use a similar approach but checks whether `os.geteuid()` is 0 or not. Therefore, I don't need to install twice in case `setup.py` is not run as root.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. The above isn't actually writing the files, it just sets `data_files` to an empty list if it doesn't have write access (so you don't get the exception when `setup` attempts to write)